# Apply format when calling template

Tags: xslt, syntax

I am stuck on a syntax issue. I have the following table data

```
<td>
<xsl:call-template name="DateDiff">
  <xsl:with-param name="firstdate" select="@Current_x0020_POP_x0020_End_x002" />
  <xsl:with-param name="seconddate" select="ddwrt:Today()" />
 </xsl:call-template>
<td>
```

I would like to conditionally format the data (say make the font red) if the date difference is less than 100 days. I know I can do if-test statement if it were a single data field. I don't know how to construct the code when calling a template. I am using SharePoint 2010 - XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out...

```
        <xsl:variable name="DaysRemaining">     
        <xsl:call-template name="DateDiff">
        <xsl:with-param name="firstdate" select="@Current_x0020_POP_x0020_End_x002" />
        <xsl:with-param name="seconddate" select="ddwrt:Today()" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$DaysRemaining &lt; 100">
            <span style="color:red"><xsl:copy-of select="$DaysRemaining"/> </span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$DaysRemaining"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
```